# numba: how to understand the stride

Tags: cuda, numba

Let's have a look at the following code:

```
from numba import cuda
import numpy as np

@cuda.jit
def add1(x, y, r):
    i = cuda.grid(1)
    if i < len(r):
        r[i] = x[i] + y[i]

@cuda.jit
def add2(x, y, r):

    start = cuda.grid(1)
    stride = cuda.gridsize(1)
    for i in range(start, x.shape[0], stride):
        r[i] = x[i] + y[i]

if __name__ == '__main__':

    n = 50000000
    x = np.arange(n)
    y = 2*x
    out = np.empty_like(x)

    threads_per_block = 128
    blocks_per_grid = n//threads_per_block + 1
    add1[blocks_per_grid, threads_per_block](x, y, out)
    d = abs(out - x - y).sum()
    print(d)
    out = np.empty_like(x)
    add2[blocks_per_grid, threads_per_block](x, y, out)
    d = abs(out - x - y).sum()
    print(d)
```

Both `add1` and `add2` can correctly add x/y, but the process of `add1`/`add2` is different.

I can understand `add1`: it add an element of `x`/`y` in one thread, and cuda will start many threads. Finally, it add all element of `x`/`y`.

But I don't understand `add2`. I think there is some overlay calculation. For example, if stride=10, start=0, it will calculate the element of 0~9. Then, start=1, it will calculate the elment of 1~10, and the element of 1~9 are calculate twice. However, if I print i in `add2`, I find all element is only calculate one time.

How to understand the `stride` in `add2`?

Comment: " if stride=10, start=0, it will calculate the element of 0~9", -- no it will calculate elements 0, 10, 20, .... "Then, start=1, it will calculate the elment of 1~10" -- it will calculate elements 1, 11, 21, ..

Comment: But, if start=10, it re-calculate 10, 20 .... which has been calculated when start=0.

Comment: No it doesn't because start is never 10 in that case. Stride the the size of the grid. Stride = 10 means start is only 0...9 because there are only 10 threads

Comment: Thank you for your reply, and I have more understanding about cuda. But I still have a question. For `add1`, I find that if threads_per_block = 256, blocks_per_grid = 32, the result is incorrect. I think the reason is that cuda only start 256*32=8192 threads, which do not cover all 50000000 elements. If I set blocks_per_grid = n//threads_per_block + 1, the `add1` will return correct x+y. Does it means the cuda start 50000000 threads? If not, how does cuda finish calcualtion for 50000000 elements?

Comment: Please read the linked duplicate. It explains exactly how this design pattern works